# What does X evaluate to in the second operand of a predicate such as "example([X|L1], [X,X|L2])"

Tags: prolog

I am trying to solve a problem where every element of a list is duplicated for which the solution is as follows:

```
duplicate([],[]).
duplicate([X|Xs],[X,X|Ys]) :-
   duplicate(Xs,Ys).
```

I know that Prolog unifies X with the first element of the list of Xs, but what does it unify with/do at the second operand/list if it is already unified with the first list?

Comment: It is not that "X" evaluates to a different value in the second case . Every occurrence of `X` within the clause will have exactly the same value .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to try and explain how this predicate works, because I think there is something amiss in your expectation of what Prolog is going to do and I'm not altogether sure what it is. Often, new users of Prolog expect that the final argument of a predicate is special somehow, in emulation of a return value in a conventional language with expression evaluation semantics. Your wording makes me think that you might think there is something procedural about Prolog causing it to process arguments from left to right. Neither of these are true. What actually matters here is what is instantiated when Prolog goes to prove a goal.

The most obtuse, but probably the most concrete way to see how Prolog is reasoning about this goal would be to invoke it with two variables and look at what you get back:

```
?- duplicate(X,Y).
X = Y, Y = [] ;

X = [_8100],
Y = [_8100, _8100] ;

X = [_8100, _8118],
Y = [_8100, _8100, _8118, _8118] ;

X = [_8100, _8118, _8136],
Y = [_8100, _8100, _8118, _8118, _8136, _8136] .
```

You could keep asking for answers but probably you get the point by now. What's worth noting about this is that Prolog is generating both lists, one with a list of unique variables, and one with those same variables duplicated. It's managing to do this without knowing anything about what those variables actually are. More directly, these are all examples of unifications that Prolog can do:

```
?- X = [Y1,Y2|Ys].
X = [Y1, Y2|Ys].

?- [Y1,Y2|Ys] = X.
X = [Y1, Y2|Ys].
```

There is nothing directional here, and Prolog is having no problem peeling off bits of structure. You can bind these variables post-hoc as well:

```
?- [Y1,Y2|Ys] = X, Y2 = foo, Ys = [].
Y2 = foo,
Ys = [],
X = [Y1, foo].
```

So doing something involving the same variable multiple times is really not a problem at all:

```
?- L1 = [X|Xs], L2 = [X,X|Ys].
L1 = [X|Xs],
L2 = [X, X|Ys].

?- L1 = [X|Xs], L2 = [X,X|Ys], X = foo.
L1 = [foo|Xs],
X = foo,
L2 = [foo, foo|Ys].

?- L2 = [X,X|Ys], L1 = [X|Xs], L1 = [1,2,3,4].
L2 = [1, 1|Ys],
X = 1,
L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
Xs = [2, 3, 4].
```

I don't see anything surprising there, but I don't see anything surprising about `duplicate/2` either. Did you find any of that surprising? If so, that might help me narrow in on the misundertanding.

Also, it should not, but may, surprise you to see this other instantiation pattern:

```
?- duplicate(A, [1,1,2,2,3,3]).
A = [1, 2, 3].
```

This follows from the others, but if it seems ludicrous then we still need to figure out where the misunderstanding is.